# VS2015 c++ project has VS2013 v120 toolset and fails to build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Even the template application (Grid App) fails to build and throws following error list:

```
Error   C2039   'ReleaseControlBlock' : is not a member of '__abi_FTMWeakRefData'   in collection.h
Error   C2039   'ReleaseControlBlock' : is not a member of '__abi_FTMWeakRefData'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\ppltasks.h   4737
Error   C2039   'ReleaseControlBlock' : is not a member of '__abi_FTMWeakRefData'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vccorlib.h   1020
Error   C2039   'ReleaseControlBlock' : is not a member of '__abi_FTMWeakRefData'   c:\users\***\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\skin\skin\app.xaml.h 26
Error   C3861   '__abi_translateCurrentException': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\collection.h 212
Error   C3861   '__abi_translateCurrentException': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vccorlib.h   986
```

Total of 63 same errors. Even blank app fails with the same error list. What is strange, is that I use Visual Studio 2015, but the projeсt toolset is set to Visual Studio 2013 (v120) and there is no 2015 option.

### UPDATE

Turned out that projects, created in VS 2015 somehow use VS 2013 (v120) toolset and therefore fail to build. However there is no other option available except (v120) toolset

Comment: Some of your code might be helpful.

Comment: The deal is that the code plays no role. Its the platform toolset

Comment: Did you install the platform toolset when installing VS? You need to mark it explicitly. Go to Software and Change/Repair the VS Install and check for the Toolset.